# Kotlin data class Jackson @JsonProperty not honored

Tags: jackson, kotlin, feign

I'm wiring up Feign to POST using a Kotlin data class.

The API I'm calling expects {..."brandInfo":{"TPID":1}...}

My understanding is, if the jackson-module-kotlin dependency wasn't being picked up correctly, Feign wouldn't be able to POST at all, because Jackson encoding would fail outright.

However, Feign is able to POST, and Jackson is able to encode, but no matter what I do, what's being posted is {..."brandInfo":{"tpid":1}...}, despite the brandInfo val being annotated with @JsonProperty("TPID").

What am I missing?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class KBrandInfo (
    @JsonProperty("TPID") //not honored
    val TPID: Long
)


interface KConversationServiceClient {
    @RequestLine("POST v2/conversations")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    fun createConversation(createConversation: KCreateConversation): String
}


@Provides
public KConversationServiceClient getKConversationServiceClient(
        @Named("conversationServiceUrl") String baseUri,
        Feign.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .decoder(new StringDecoder())
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(jacksonObjectMapper())) //does this need some extra configuration in order to pick up @JsonProperty annotations?
            .requestInterceptor(requestTemplate ->
                    requestTemplate
                            .header("requestId", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .target(KConversationServiceClient.class, baseUri);
}


<properties>
    ...
    <feign.version>9.3.1</feign.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.1.51</kotlin.version>
    ...
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-gson</artifactId>
        <version>${feign.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--Kotlin + Java + Maven implies some funky temporal dependencies and handling of annotation processing when building-->
        <!--* https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html-->
        <!--* https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html-->
        <!--* https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/blob/master/maven/dagger-maven-example/pom.xml-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        ...
```

Comment: I'm calling jacksonObjectMapper() as instructed by https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin. Before .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(jacksonObjectMapper())), I've tried configuring it using ObjectMapper mapper = jacksonObjectMapper();
        JacksonEncoder encoder = new JacksonEncoder(mapper);
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy());
        mapper.registerModule(new KotlinModule()); to no avail.

Comment: MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES is for incoming, so it doesn't work. But mapper.configure(USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING, true); seems like it has the desired effect, cheers.

Comment: Yes I was just wondering if it was worth investigating if that property was breaking something on outgoing.
I've been looking at the differences between 2.7.9 and master, and I see there's a [caveat in 2.7.9](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/tree/jackson-module-kotlin-2.7.9#caveats) that is no longer in master: "Currently we use parameter name information in Kotlin that is compatible with Kotlin M8 through M11". Could that explain the problem? Are you able to upgrade Jackson and jackson-module-kotlin?

Comment: Nice find about USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING.

Comment: On second thought, doesn't the fact I explicitly have to mapper.configure(USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING, true); mean @JsonProperty("TPID") is in fact still being ignored? 

I should be able to upgrade.

Comment: Use jackson-module-kotlin https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin for Kotlin

Comment: Still no luck even with `jackson-module-kotlin`

Answer (score 3):

What helped to me was to specify that the annotation should be applied to the getter: `@get:JsonProperty("TPID")`